# Como tratar acentuação em arquivos .bat?

Tags: batch, powershell, ms-dos

bom dia!

Estou com uma dificuldade em realizar a copia de um arquivo de uma pasta para outra através do comando copy.

Estou utilizando o Encoding UTF-8, mas o cmd não consegue tratar a acentuação para linha abaixo:

```
copy "C:\SVN\Makro\Templates e Orientações operacionais\02 - Templates da Fábrica de Testes\FTMakro - MKRXXXXXX - QA de EFN.xlsx" "C:\SVN\Makro\Demandas\Fábrica Não Definida\EFN_%NomeDemanda%\01_Artefatos_de_Entrada_e_QA\FTMakro - %NomeDemanda% - QA de EFN.xlsx"
```

E retorna o erro:

```
C:\SVN\Makro\Demandas\Fábrica Não Definida\EFN_za>copy "C:\SVN\Makro\Templates e Orienta?º?Áes operacionais\02 - Templates da F?íbrica de Testes\FTMakro - MKRXX XXXX - QA de EFN.xlsx" "C:\SVN\Makro\Demandas\F?íbrica N?úo Definida\EFN_za\01_A rtefatos_de_Entrada_e_QA\FTMakro - za - QA de EFN.xlsx" O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
```

Por favor, podem me ajudar a resolver a tratativa?
Obrigado.

Comment: usar uma tabela de caracteres ASCI II, foi o que resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 19):

Execute dois passos simples:

1. Salve o arquivo .bat com charset UTF-8
2. Especifique o charset dentro do arquivo .bat usando o comando `chcp` (`Change Code Page`).
   Para UTF-8, o código é 65001

Exemplo

**foo.bat**

```
chcp 65001
copy "C:\ação.txt" "C:\ação3.txt"
```

No Windows CMD, basta chamar o .bat normalmente.

```
C:\>foo.bat
```

Caso a tela do CMD não esteja exibindo os caracteres corretamente, verifique o tipo de font que está configurada.

Com o botão direito do mouse, clique na barra superior da janela e selecione "Properties" (Propriedades). Escolha uma font compatível com UTF-8.

Comment: Com ```chcp 65001``` funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode substituir o caminho completo até o arquivo para o *"short path"* caminho curto, para que o DOS consiga compreender.

Pode utilizar o comando:

```
for %I in (.) do echo %~sI
```

Resultado

> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\Desktop

```
dir /x
```

Para identificar o short path do arquivo.

Exemplo:

> 18/11/2015  15:42            13.948 ALTER_~1.ODT
>   alter_database_character_oracle .odt
>
> 10/02/2014  09:23           168.506 CODIGO~1.PDF
>   CodigodeEticaeCondutadaLG.pdf
>
> 18/11/2015  15:42             8.095 COMAND~1.SQL Comandos_Oracle.sql
>
> 02/08/2013  18:38           708.096 ORCAME~1.DOC Orcamento de
>   Pessoal.doc
>
> 21/07/2015  09:33             1.039 SQLTOO~1.LNK SQLTools 1.7.lnk

ai basta pegar os short path.

C:\Users\ADMINI~1\Desktop\ALTER_~1.ODT

Comment: Hoppy, obrigado pela direção. Consegui absorver o contexto, mas ainda não consegui compreender como aplicar o *short path*.

Comment: entra na pasta onde está o arquivo pelo DOS e digita o comando: "for %I in (.) do echo %~sI" o resultado será o short path da pasta, agora digita "dir /x" vocÊ obterá o short path do arquivo. juntando os 2, você possui o caminho completo do arquivo.

Comment: Ah, bacana! Obrigado! 
Vou tentar aqui.

Comment: comenta o resultado, depois. abraços!

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado, Hoppy! O *short path*, deve ser usado pasta a pasta.

Comment: cada pasta tem seu shortpath definido. você pode usar esse comando também para obter o shortpath completo do arquivo: "cmd /c for %A in ("C:\Documents and Settings\User\NTUSER.DAT") do @echo %~sA"

Answer (score 4):

É só você inserir este código no início do seu .bat

```
@CHCP 1252 >NUL
```

Comment: Funcionou pra mim, mas o que esse trecho de código significa? Parece que ">NULL" é a chave para a magia acontecer.

Comment: Pelo que entendi é para ocultar as saídas do comando https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148701/como-ocultar-a-sa%C3%ADda-de-comando-no-cmd

Answer (score 1):

> Não precisa de tanta burocracia, caso queiram colocar uma palavra
>   acentuada dentro de um arquivo batch, basta fazer o seguinte:
>
> 1 - na área de trabalho, segurem SHIFT, cliquem com o botão direito do mouse em um campo vazio, vão em "Abrir janela de comando
>   aqui"
>
> 2 - digitem: Echo."Palavra acentuada">palavra.txt
>
> 3 - Abram o arquivo "palavra.txt" e terão a palavra com o caractere do
>   acento corrigido, feito isso basta copiar a palavra para dentro do
>   Batch que ele já irá mostrar a palavra com acento.
>
> obs: em "Palavra acentuada" coloquem a palavra que vocês querem
>   acentuar, não precisa ter aspas

Comment: É mais chatinho pra fazer, mas pra mim funcionou. tks