# Qual codificação usar para script do CMD?

Tags: c#, batch, cmd

O Prompt de Comandos do Windows usa uma tabela ASCII diferente da nossa, que inclusive eu não sei qual é.

Tanto é que um batch com caracteres especiais quando impresso na tela ficam estranhos: `Opção de área de influência` fica `OpþÒo de ßrea de influÛncia`.

Pra corrigir isso, sem sacrificar o que será exibido na tela, usa-se uma tabela de substituição de caracteres especiais por outros que são ilegíveis mas que representam o caractere na tela ASCII do CMD.

Exemplo: escrevendo no batch `Op‡Æo de  rea de influˆncia` ele printa na tela `Opção de área de influência` como devia ser.

Eu não achei um padrão da tabela ASCII com esses correspondentes, então tenho que fazer a comparação de um por um.

Pra facilitar eu quero fazer uma rotina em C# que depois do batch escrito ela o leia e os caracteres especiais sejam substituídos pelos correspondentes. O problema é que a saída substitui os caracteres especiais por `?`. Eu suponho que isso seja problema de codificação.

Eu quero saber qual codificação usar para ler o arquivo e para gravar as alterações no novo.

O switch que eu montei:

```
switch (Letra)
{
    case 'á': return ' ';
    case 'à': return '…';
    case 'ã': return 'Æ';
    case 'ä': return '„';
    case 'â': return 'ƒ';
    case 'Á': return 'µ';
    case 'À': return '·';
    case 'Ã': return 'Ç';
    case 'Ä': return 'Ž';
    case 'Â': return '¶';
    case 'é': return '‚';
    case 'è': return 'Š';
    case 'ë': return '‰';
    case 'ê': return 'ˆ';
    case 'É': return '';
    case 'È': return 'Ô';
    case 'Ë': return 'Ó';
    case 'Ê': return 'Ò';
    case 'í': return '¡';
    case 'ì': return '';
    case 'ï': return '‹';
    case 'î': return 'Œ';
    case 'Í': return 'Ö';
    case 'Ì': return 'Þ';
    case 'Ï': return 'Ø';
    case 'Î': return '×';
    case 'ó': return '¢';
    case 'ò': return '•';
    case 'õ': return 'ä';
    case 'ö': return '”';
    case 'ô': return '“';
    case 'Ó': return 'à';
    case 'Ò': return 'ã';
    case 'Õ': return 'å';
    case 'Ö': return '™';
    case 'Ô': return 'â';
    case 'ú': return '£';
    case 'ù': return '—';
    case 'ü': return '';
    case 'û': return '–';
    case 'Ú': return 'é';
    case 'Ù': return 'ë';
    case 'Ü': return 'š';
    case 'Û': return 'ê';
    case 'ç': return '‡';
    case 'Ç': return '€';
    default: return Letra;
}
```

Comment: "O Prompt de Comandos do Windows usa uma tabela ASCII diferente da nossa, que inclusive eu não sei qual é." na verdade ASCII é igual em qq lugar. O que muda é o ASCII extended, com páginas de código que dependem da configuração do OS. Seu switch vai ter problema, pois só vai funcionar pra uma das inúmeras páginas de código existentes.

Comment: Pra nós aqui, as mais comuns são a 850 e a 437, mas isso varia muito. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

Comment: Outra dica: Quando usar esse tipo de conversão, não ponha o caractere digitado no editor, use o código dele, senão o código fonte fica muito amarrado ao editor em uso. E pode dar problema ao abrir o fonte em utf-8, por exemplo. PS: eu imagino que o C# já tenha algo pronto pra fazer essas conversões.

Comment: Não precisa fazer essa gambiarra.. rsrs.. veja aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105648/4793

Answer (score -3):

Nesse caso, pode-se mudar a codificação do prompt. Salve o arquivo na codificação **ANSI(window-1252)** padrão do bloco de notas.

Ex:

```
$ cmd_opercoes.bat
Cßlculos simples:
2+2= 4
2-2= 0
2*2= 4
2/2= 1
2%2= 0

$ chcp 1252
Página de código ativa: 1252

$ cmd_opercoes.bat
Cálculos simples:
2+2= 4
2-2= 0
2*2= 4
2/2= 1
2%2= 0
```