# Como ocultar a saída de comando no CMD?

Tags: cmd

Tenho um arquivo `.bat` e nele há o comando:

```
chcp 65001
```

Que resulta na saída no CMD:

```
Página de código ativa: 65001
```

Mas eu quero que essa mensagem, exibida depois que o comando é executado, fique oculta para o usuário.
Qual é o comando no CMD que faz isso?

OBS: Uso o Windows 8.

Comment: Só tem isso no batch? Se sim, acho que só colocar um /K no final da instrução.

Comment: Não, tem outras instruções. Ao colocar o /K diz no cmd formato de parâmetro incorreto - /K

Comment: É, acho que isso só funcionaria com uma instrução apenas. Eu não tenho windows pra testar no momento, mas você já tentou dar a instrução `echo off` antes desta linha? Ou talvez colocar  `>NUL` logo depois da instrução que deseja silenciar. Só constando que eu realmente não lembro, estou te dizendo tudo o que me veio na cabeça, hehe.

Comment: O " echo off" já tinha colocado. Mas não sabia desse " > NUL ". Depois que coloquei o  " > NUL " deu certo a mensagens indesejada não aparece mais. Obrigado.

Answer (score 15):

Existe 3 coisas a serem feitas:

- `@echo off`

  Oculta os comandos digitados pelo usuário, fora isto ele também oculta a pasta atual que esta navegando via comando. Note que o `@` serve para ocultar a resposta do comando `echo off`.

  1. Com `echo on` (padrão):

     ```
     echo Oi!

     pause
     ```

     Exibe algo como (note **que aparece** um espaço antes da primeira linha):

     > C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop>echo Oi!
     >   Oi!
     >   
     >   C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop>pause
     >   Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

     Veja que tanto as respostas quando os comandos são exibidos
  2. Com `echo off` sem @:

     ```
     echo off

     echo Oi!

     pause
     ```

     Exibe algo como (note **que aparece** um espaço antes da primeira linha):

     > C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop>echo off
     >   Oi!
     >   Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

     Veja que tanto as respostas quando os comandos são exibidos
  3. Com `echo off` **com** @:

     ```
     @echo off

     echo "Oi"

     pause
     ```

     Exibe algo como (note que **não aparece** um espaço antes da primeira linha):

     > Oi!
     >   Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
- `>nul`

  O `nul` é um objeto que descarta qualquer dado escrito, o `>` é o sinal para apontar aonde deve ser gravado os dados de saída ao invés de exibir na tela, note que para cada novo comando você deve adicionar um novo `>nul`, por exemplo:

  ```
  @echo off

  echo Foo >nul

  echo Baz

  echo Bar

  pause
  ```

  A resposta será:

  > Baz
  >   Bar
  >   Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

  Se fizer assim:

  ```
  @echo off

  echo Foo >nul

  echo Baz >nul

  echo Bar >nul

  pause
  ```

  A resposta será:

  > Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

  E com `>nul` no comando `pause` não terá resposta alguma:

  ```
  @echo off

  echo Foo >nul

  echo Baz >nul

  echo Bar >nul

  pause >nul
  ```
- `2>&1`

  - O `0` é o `stdin`, é a entrada, ou seja o que é enviado para os comandos, por exemplo comandos digitados pelo usuário, ou comandos em um script .bat ou .sh
  - O `1` é o `stdout`, ou seja a saída, ou output
  - O `2` é o `stderr`, saída de erros, quando ocorre alguma falha

  No caso não precisamos do 0 pois o `echo off` já oculta os dados de entrada, então usamos o 2 para direcionar a saída para o 1, então por exemplo, se fizer isto:

  ```
  @echo off

  cd DiretorioInexistente >nul

  pause >nul
  ```

  Vai aparecer algo como:

  > O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.

  Mas se fizer isto não vai exibir nada:

  ```
  @echo off

  cd DiretorioInexistente >nul 2>&1

  pause >nul
  ```

### Concluindo

Se quiser ocultar tudo, menos os erros (acho que é preferivel), use assim:

```
@echo off

meucomando argumento1 argumento2 >nul
```

Se quiser ocultar tudo, use assim:

```
@echo off

meucomando argumento1 argumento2 >nul 2>&1
```

> Não tenho muito conhecimento, se tiver alguma falha por comentar ou qualquer coisa.

Então o código final pode ficar assim:

```
@echo off

chcp 65001 >nul 2>&1

echo Olá

pause
```

**Nota:**
Ao usar o `chcp` pode eventualmente aparecer uma mensagem assim:

> The system cannot write to the specified device.

Para "corrigir", terá que clicar na barra de titulo > Propriedades > Font > Selecione a fonte Lucida Console

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92120/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-como-ocultar-a-saida-de-comando-no) e pode prosseguir lá se alguém tiver interesse, basta clicar no link.

Answer (score 2):

---

- **<kbd>`Update Redirecionamento de erros + saídas normais para arquivo:`</kbd>**

  ---
- **Saída de Erro + Saída Padrão**  para **arquivo**
- **`stderr        +       stdout`** para **arquivo**

  ---

Para ocultar os possessíveis **erros** + **avisos** + saídas **normais**, mas redirecionar essas possíveis saídas para um arquivo, apenas apontamos para um **arquivo** receber o **redirecionando** da saída **'stderr'** para a saída **'stdout'**: **`2>&1`**  == **`stderr > & stdout`**

Basicamente, fazendo o **redirecionamento** para um **arquivo**, onde este vai receber a saída **stderr** que terá sua saída, por sua vez, também **redirecionada** para a saída **stdout**, dessa forma:

```bat
commando >.\arquivo.txt strr>&stout
```

---

Para testar esse comportamento podemos executar um comando que retorna uma saída normal e outro retorne erro com erro, já redirecionando o erro da saída de erro para e saída normal, onde estamos redirecionando para um arquivo.txt.

---

```bat
(chcp 1252 & echo/Saída normal & copy /b 0 nul) >arquivo.txt 2>&1
```

Os comandos adicionaram no **arquivo.txt** as **saídas normais + erros redirecionados** para a **saída padrão**:

---

`Página de código ativa: 65001` => do comando:**`chcp 1252`**

`Saída normal`=> do comando:**`echo/Saída normal`**

`O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.`  => do comando:**`copy /b 0 nul`**

---

---

Resumindo, o comando retorna na sua saída padrão (**`stdout`**) para o **arquivo:** **`arquivo.txt`**, onde os possíveis erros da saída **`stderr`** estão sendo redirecionados para a saída **`stdout`**.

---

---

> > Um curto **comando** que funciona tanto na **linha de comando** e como no **bat** ocultando **saídas, erros e avisos**...
>
> **<kbd>`>nul chcp 65001`</kbd>** **ou** **<kbd>`>nul 2>&1 chcp 65001`</kbd>**

***Basicamente redireciona saída para***  **<kbd>`dispositivo nul`</kbd>** 
***não havendo saída visível do comando.***

- Alguns exemplos de **uso** e seu **comportamento** para

  **1. Saídas Normais = <kbd>`echo/exemplo`</kbd>**

  **2. Avisos         = <kbd>`chcp 65001`</kbd>**

  **3. Erro           = <kbd>`dir /o0`</kbd>**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```bat
@echo off & cls & echo/ 

echo/exemplo 1 :: não vê nada & echo/ 
>nul^
      (
       echo/exemplo 1 :: você não vê nada
       chcp 65001
       dir /o0  ^< este comando gera erro^!! :: Formato de parâmetro incorreto - "0". 
       echo/exemplo 1 :: você continua sem ver nada^!! 
       ) 2>nul

echo/exemplo 2 :: ve soh saida/avisos & echo/
2>nul^
      (
       echo/exemplo 2 :: você não vê possíveis erros mas vê as saídas
       chcp 65001 
       dir /o0   ^< este comando gera erro^!! 
       echo/exemplo 2 :: e você não viu o erro do comando^!!
       echo/
       )

echo/exemplo 3 :: você vê somente possíveis erros & echo/
>nul^
      (
       echo/exemplo 3 ::: você só vê o erro
       chcp 65001
       dir /o0   ^< este comando gera erro^!! :: Formato de parâmetro incorreto - "0".
       echo/exemplo 3 ::: e você soh ver o erro^!! 
       )

rem :: Ou ainda dessa forma ::

@echo off 

rem :: nem erro nem saída ::

dir /o0  >nul 2>&1 ^< esse comando gera erro e você não vê o erro
dir ,    >nul 2>&1 ^< esse comando gera saída e você não vê
```

---

Comment: Se possível deixe na resposta também uma explicação desses parâmetros e porque esse comando faz o que o [OP](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2658/86952) perguntou.

Comment: O que sua resposta acrescenta à anterior, que já tem 2 anos desde a escrita? Vejo que a sua é apenas um pequeno tópico que foi tratado pela outra resposta

Comment: Caro Kapputz a minha resposta é limpa e clara e esta e o melhor dividida em tópicos que explicam passo a passo "tecnicamente" ao invés de dar apenas um código "testa ai", então com todo respeito discordo da sua alfinetada sobre a minha resposta. É totalmente necessário explicar cada item e como funciona o INPUT e OUTPUT e que tipos de variações o echo off pode causar.

Comment: Rapa, n entendo o ambiente,

Comment: Coloquei apenas um resposta curta, vem operador e me pede p comentar,  vem um outro e pede p aponta diferenças, vem voce e se manifesta "ofendido/ou/alfinetado"

Comment: Estou sendo educado contigo e não estou ofendido, a questão é que você alfinetou a resposta e expliquei a necessidade dela ser técnica, porque somos um site para aprender a programar e não para compartilhar coisas prontas, entender o comportamento de um código ou API é totalmente interessante para adaptar a diferentes necessidades, espero que compreenda melhor a comunidade e passe a aceitar criticas construtivas sem levar para outro lado. Tenha um bom dia caro kapputz.

Comment: @Gilherme Nascimento, **nul** é diferente de **null** >null cria arquivo, >nul oculta saída.. tem diferença, veja sua resposta onde figura: echo Foo >null

Comment: zOK, desaculpa, desculpa...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Qual sua motivação para propor seu comentário? Permita perguntar, mas seu comentário foi motivado por?

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe vai me perguntar quase um ano depois de eu escrever meu comentário? Pelo visto, foi porque eu não vi nada de novidade na resposta (nem digno de ser escrito como resposta) quando a li. Não vou comparar com o estado atual da resposta, visto que o contexto de escrita era referente a versão de 17/dezembro/2018, não a de abril/2019

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado inocente eh inocente em qualquer tempo, c n responder permite entender o entendido! Obrigado

Comment: @PedroGaspar sua postura foi relevante e necessária, entendo hoje, não entendi no tempo, hoje lhe sou grato, e, cito, foi uma das poucas observações pertinentes e construtivas operada por usuário nessa plataforma. Entendi que eh livre a ação de responder, contudo, entendi seu comentário tardiamente. Essa resposta foi uma das 5 foi primeiras por eu postado. Hoje entendo a necessidade de explicar os conteúdo postado.

Comment: Que bom que ajudei de alguma forma @ItWasn'tMe, o SO serve para isso mesmo, nos ajudarmos mutuamente e criarmos juntos uma biblioteca ótima de conteúdo na área. Eu não acompanhei na época mas vi agora que rolou uma certa discussão por causa desse post. Eu também apanhei um pouco quando cheguei e foi um pouco duro entender o funcionamento, mas é assim mesmo. Muita gente leva pro lado pessoal, fica chateada e desiste, sem tentar entender primeiro como a comunidade funciona. E não pode haver arrogância de quem chega, tem que ouvir os mais velhos e tentar se adaptar.

Comment: Também pode parecer duro quando recebemos certos comentários, mas temos que entender que quem tá na ativa, participando na comunidade pra valer mesmo, acaba tendo que avaliar, editar, comentar, responder, muita coisa durante o dia, isso tudo conciliando com o emprego real do indivíduo (porque todo mundo aqui está trabalhando de graça para construir uma comunidade melhor), então não dá pra ficar sendo simpático e explicativo sempre, muitas vezes os usuários escolhem ser mais sucintos e objetivos, e isso pode soar duro pra quem chega.

Comment: Se tiver interesse, eu falei um pouco sobre minha experiência inicial aqui no SOpt no meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7421/86952, e também tem o relato de outros usuários lá, talvez seja interessante para você e para outros que passem por aqui.

Comment: @PedroGaspar muito obrigado, vou seguir vosso conselho!