# Como apresentar a acentuação correta no retorno do cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação

Considerando um método para listar os arquivos de uma pasta usando `ProcessBuilder` tenho o retorno incorreto das palavras acentuadas.

**Código**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class TesteCMD {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    LinkedHashSet<String> comandos = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    TesteCMD cmd = new TesteCMD();

    comandos.add("cd C:/Vídeos/Filmes");
    comandos.add("dir /b");

    System.out.println(cmd.executar(comandos.toArray(new String[comandos.size()])));
  }

  public String executar(String... comandos) {
    StringBuilder saida = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader leitor;
    ProcessBuilder processos;
    Process processo;
    String linha;

    try {
      processos = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", String.join(" && ", comandos));
      processo = processos.start();
      processo.waitFor();
      leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processo.getInputStream()));

      while ((linha = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
        saida.append(linha).append("\n");
      }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
      return ex.getMessage();
    }

    return saida.toString();
  }
}
```

**Pasta**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Saída**

```
run:
A Viagem de Chihiro (2001)
Batman - The Dark Knight Returns (2012)
Contos de Terramar (2006)
From up on Poppy Hill (2011)
Lilo e Stitch (2002)
Man of Steel (2013)
Meu Amigo Totoro (1988)
Meus Vizinhos os Yamadas (1999)
Nausica� do Vale do Vento (1984)
O Castelo Animado (2004)
O Castelo no C�u (1986)
O Mundo dos Pequeninos (2010)
O Rei Le�o
O Reino dos Gatos (2002)
O Servi�o de Entregas da Kiki (1989)
Only Yesterday (1991)
Pom Poko (1994)
Ponyo (2008)
Porco Rosso (1992)
Princesa Mononoke (1997)
Shingeki no Kyojin (2013)
Sussuros do Cora��o (1995)
The Animatrix (2003)
The Matrix (1999)
T�mulo dos Vagalumes (1988)
UP - Altas Aventuras (2009)
V de Vingan�a (2005)
Vidas ao Vento (2013)

CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

Eu sei que tem outros modos de listar os arquivos e não é essa a questão. Eu gostaria de saber como resolver para que o retorno dos meus processos sejam acentuados corretamente e também o porquê disso ocorrer.

Eu já tentei adicionar o `encoding` *(UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 e windows-1252)* no `InputStreamReader` mas não corrigiu o problema.

**Observação**

Já tentei com outros comandos, por exemplo:

```
System.out.println(cmd.executar("@ECHO Teste acentuação"));
```

*Resulta em:*

```
run:
Teste acentua��o

CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

*Quando deveria ser:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize o comando `chcp` para trocar o charset do **cmd**.

Para o UTF-8 o código é **65001**

O comando a executar:

```
chcp 65001
```

Não sei ao certo onde poderia executar dentro dessas funções que apresentou.

Pode experimentar o concatenador de múltiplos comandos, o caracter `&`

```
System.out.println(cmd.executar("chcp 65001 & @ECHO Teste acentuação"))
```

Alternativamente pode invocar um arquvio `.bat`. Exemplo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105648/4793

Para saber mais sobre a concatenação de múltiplos comandos e redirecionamento de saídas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719174/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-line

## PrintStream

Experimente também trocar esse trecho:

```
System.out.println(cmd.executar(comandos.toArray(new String[comandos.size()])));
```

Por esse:

```
PrintStream p = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
p.println(cmd.executar(comandos.toArray(new String[comandos.size()])));
```

## Codificação do editor de texto

Também pode ter outros motivos como o editor de texto. Verifique qual encoding está sendo salvo o editor do código.

## Observação

Caso esteja chamando o script JAVA pelo prompt do Windows pode ser apenas a configuração do prompt. Experimente:

```
chcp 65001
java /local/do/app/java.jar
```

## Encoding 850

Teste também o código 850

```
PrintStream p = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "CP850");
p.println(cmd.executar(comandos.toArray(new String[comandos.size()])));
```

Nesse caso, remova aquele comando: `chcp 65001 &`

*Aqui apresentei exemplo para UTF-8. Certifique-se qual charset está usando e aplique o código adequado.

Comment: Não funcionou. Fiz a chamada da seguinte forma `chcp 65001 && @ECHO Teste acentuação` e recebi o texto `P�gina de c�digo ativa: 65001` e `Teste acentua��o`. Mudei também `InputStreamReader` para ler `UTF-8`

Comment: A diferença entre `&` e `&&` é só se ele vai fazer a segunda instrução caso a primeira de `exit(1)`. Mas de qualquer forma alterei e continua sem retornar com a acentuação correta

Comment: Tente usar a classe PrintStream. Coloquei exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou também. O que funcionou foi fazer o `InputStreamReader` usar o `CP850`

Comment: Será que se eu colocar o `chcp 850` e o `InputStreamReder` pra `CP850` vai funcionar em qualquer computador?

Comment: O padrão do Windows é code page 850. Deve funcionar bem se o input e output do JAVA estiverem também no padrão. O padrão do JAVA espera sempre o 850 (em windows). O ideal é detectar automaticamente e fornecer opção de ajuste manual ao usuário.

Comment: Opa beleza, obrigado pela resposta