# Recusa de acento com .bat

Tags: acentuação, bat

Tenho um .bat que quando executado faz a chamada de um script.

Meu problema é que os arquivos que são chamados pelo script tem acentos do tipo "ç,á,ã", coisas desse tipo.

Sendo assim, quando ele procura o arquivo, não encontra o nome certo.

```
Nome do arquivo: "Procuração.xls"
Chamada do script: "Porcura$ÕAo.xls"
```

Com isso ele não encontra o arquivo certo para executar.

Já vi vários tópicos sobre isso, mas não consegui implementar nenhum.

Atualmente estou usando

```
U:
CHCP 1252
cd U:\PastaAberta\Progan
ECHO Aguarde o script executar...
Rscript script02.R
pause
```

Comment: Poste o seu código, para analise

Comment: veja se as resposta dessa pergunta feita antes te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101740/como-tratar-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-arquivos-bat

Comment: @WictorChaves coloquei a forma que estou usando, que ainda está me dando o erro

Comment: É o script que defini qual arquivo abrir? Porque se for o problema esta no script e não no bat

Comment: Com qual codificação foi criado o arquivo? Provavelmente em uma codificação diferente da do sistema aonde está chamando.

Comment: Já há uma pergunta muito semelhante a tua [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101740/como-tratar-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-arquivos-bat) aqui na SOpt. Creio que as respostas contidas ali lhe serão úteis.

Comment: tente com este codigo antes do iniciar o comando @chcp 65001